# Hide delete button inside action in odoo

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-11

How to hide delete button inside action in odoo for **particular group**.
suppose, I have two user admin and demo, created a group called button. When give rights to admin then that delete button will be visible to admin and when give rights to user then in that case only visible to user. If not given rights to user then button not visible to user.

I use the following code:

**create group in security.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>   
    <data>
        <record id="group_delete_button" model="res.groups">
            <field name="name">Button</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

**custom js to hide button for particular group**

```
renderSidebar: function ($node) {
    if (!this.sidebar && this.hasSidebar) {
        var otherItems = [];
        var has_delete_group = false;
        this.getSession().user_has_group('web.group_delete_button').then(function(has_group) {
            if (has_group) {
                has_delete_group = true
            } else {
                has_delete_group = false
            }
        }); 
        var otherItems = [];
        if (this.is_action_enabled('delete')) {
            if (has_delete_group) {
                debugger
                otherItems.push({
                    label: _t('Delete'),
                    callback: this._onDeleteRecord.bind(this),
                });
            }
        }
        if (this.is_action_enabled('create') && this.is_action_enabled('duplicate')) {
            otherItems.push({
                label: _t('Duplicate'),
                callback: this._onDuplicateRecord.bind(this),
            });
        }
        this.sidebar = new Sidebar(this, {
            editable: this.is_action_enabled('edit'),
            viewType: 'form',
            env: {
                context: this.model.get(this.handle).getContext(),
                activeIds: this.getSelectedIds(),
                model: this.modelName,
            },
            actions: _.extend(this.toolbarActions, {other: otherItems}),
        });
        this.sidebar.appendTo($node);

        // Show or hide the sidebar according to the view mode
        this._updateSidebar();
    }
}
```

This code will not work anyone can help.

Comment: Normally you just take away the delete access for groups, who should not delete things.

Comment: I got the answer. Just call willStart method.